# Pass Variable value from One React function to other (between two different Files)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am stuck on some Basic problem and don't know what should I look for...
I have tried to work with Props but I failed.

I have two Files.

First File Map.js

```js
export default function Map() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView style={styles.map}  
      initialRegion={{
      latitude: 37.78825,
      longitude: -122.4324,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    }}
  />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Second File CurrentPossition.js

```js
export default function CurrentPossition() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
  const [copiedText] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android' && !Constants.isDevice) {
        setErrorMsg(
          'Oops, this will not work on Snack in an Android emulator. Try it on your device!'
        );
        return;
      }
      let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);

    })();
  }, []);

    let text = 'Waiting..';
  if (errorMsg) {
    text = errorMsg;
  } else if (location) {
    text = JSON.stringify(location.coords.latitude);
  }
```

I would like to pass the Value from the CurrentPossition.js Variable `let text`
in to the  `latitude:`parameter of `<MapView />` component of the Map.js File.

```js
 <MapView style={styles.map}  
      initialRegion={{
      latitude: {text},
      }}
  />
```

How can I do this?

---

### 2nd Try

My Map.JS looks now like this, but I don't become the right coordinates.
When I log the Value of text - I just become `Waiting...` that's the string from
`const [text, setText] = React.useState("Waiting...");`

````js
export const MyContext = React.createContext();

export default function Map() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("Waiting...");
  console.log(text);
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ text, setText }}>

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: text,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        />
      </View>

  </MyContext.Provider>
  ); 
}```
````

Comment: are you using a state managment such as Redux ?

Comment: MapView is not a child component of CurrentPossition. So you can't just pass it's local state to MapView directly. Either store a global state (redux/flux), or use localStorage, or useContext to pass this value.
Post the entire code where you are using these components. And then I can suggest which of these options would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Add [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) in a common parent of both components and access it in the child components:

- Create the context and export it so that the child components can import it when needed

  ```
  export const MyContext = React.createContext();
   // Create state in the parent component
   const [text, setText] = React.useState("Waiting...");
  ```
- Wrap the children in this provider

  ```
  <MyContext.Provider value={{ text, setText }}>
   // children
  </MyContext.Provider>;
  ```
- in Map.js

  ```
  export default function Map() {
  return (
    <MyContext.Consumer>
      {({ text }) => (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <MapView
            style={styles.map}
            initialRegion={{
              latitude: text,
              longitude: -122.4324,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }}
          />
        </View>
      )}
    </MyContext.Consumer>
  );
  ```

  }
- in CurrentPossition.js

  ```
  import {MyContext} from "./somewhere"
  export default function CurrentPossition() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
  const [copiedText] = useState('')
  const {setText} = React.useContext(MyContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android' && !Constants.isDevice) {
        setErrorMsg(
          'Oops, this will not work on Snack in an Android emulator. Try it on your device!'
        );
        return;
      }
      let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);

    })();
  }, []);

  if (errorMsg) {
    setText(errorMsg);
  } else if (location) {
    setText(JSON.stringify(location.coords.latitude))
  }
  ```

Comment: THX for the fast answer!!!
My 2nd Try 
I become now "Waiting..." when I console.log text in Map.js.

Comment: So is this what you expected or should it have been updated at that point?

Comment: I expected the value of 
let text = JSON.stringify(location.coords.latitude);

Comment: Cadn you check whether the `setText` is reached and executed? Because if it fires, the `text` should be updated.

Comment: When I try to Log setText, I become [Function bound dispatchAction]

Comment: Can you insert a `console.log` before `setText(JSON.stringify(location.coords.latitude))` to see whether the function gets reached?